# Filter only 1st paragraph starting always with capital letters and ending with two newlines

Tags: regex

I'm trying to filter out only paragraph which must start with >FIGURE< word and must end before 2 new lines (\n\n)
Here's the text I'm working with :

```
FIGURE
     hello this a test.
     how
     are you
     I am fine, 123!.


OUT THERE
     This is ridiculous.
     Don't believe it.
     Don't believe it.
```

I tried this:`^[A-Z ]+[\w ,!.']+`
but couldn't filter next paragraph starting with >OUT THERE<`.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/YeRwSr/1

Answer (score 0):

You could capture until a newline character is encountered that is not followed by a space (or the end of the input is reached).

[`FIGURE\n(.*?)(?=\n(?! )|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/mlU6Rf/1)

Answer (score 0):

This `FIGURE[\w\W\n\r]+(>?OUT THERE)` will also do it

[image]